# Mathematical methods in physics

Tags: mathematical-physics

How to solve $\Gamma(-n)$? Which formula is good to get answer for the above question? I tried of various formulae to solve it but I couldn't make it out. What is the right way to approach the above question?

Comment: $\Gamma(-n)$ has simple poles for integers $n \ge 0$. That is, $\Gamma(z) \to (-1)^n\infty$ as $z\to -n$, but $(z+n)\Gamma(z)$ is bounded.

Comment: Simply have a look at the graphical representation of [$\Gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Answer (score 0):

Euler's reflection formula for $\Gamma(z)$ is what you want.
$$
\Gamma(-z) = \frac{-\pi}{\sin(\pi z)\Gamma(1+z)}
$$
From this formula it is clear to see that for even integers $\Gamma(n)$ is $\infty$ or undefined and for odd integers it is $\frac{\pm\pi}{\Gamma(n+1)}$. Hope this helps.

Edit:
As some have pointed out im an idiot. Eulers reflection formula is undefined for integers.

Comment: The even/odd distinction you describe is incorrect, as $\sin\pi n=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: The Gamma function's analytic continuation doesn't (cannot) incloude the negative integers...

Comment: Since sinπn = 0, can we say Gamma ( -n ) value will be  equal to ( - π ) /  0 ? In that case the answer will be ?